# Where can I find the source code for GNU stdc++ operator new?

Tags: c++

I tried here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/index.html

and I found new.h but not the code to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: In the source code, not the documentation.

Comment: @Neil: Good grief! It's you! So you're a Moorcock fan?

Comment: @Steve I was toying with FireClown. But seriously, I've been going through a lot of personal problems and just wanted to see if I'd like to get back into SO or not, so I used a pseudonym. And I decided I kind of did.

Comment: @Neil: seems to have worked, I think I've been having the same sorts of arguments with you that I did before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relevant source code for libstdc++ can be browsed online [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B;hb=HEAD). You probably want to read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_op.cc;hb=HEAD).

Comment: And [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc?view=markup).

Comment: Instead of only looking at `new_opnt.cc` or `new_op.cc`, for the complete picture look at the set of files matching `new*` and `del*` at the http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/ link.